# Libav and xaudio2 - audio not playing

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, decode, libav, xaudio2

I am trying to get audio playing with libav using xaudio2. The xaudio2 code I am using works with an older ffmpeg using avcodec_decode_audio2, but that has been deprecated for avcodec_decode_audio4. I have tried following various libav examples, but can't seem to get the audio to play. Video plays fine (or rather it just plays right fast now, as I haven't coded any sync code yet).

Firstly audio gets init, no errors, video gets init, then packet:

```
while (1) {
    //is this packet from the video or audio stream?
    if (packet.stream_index == player.v_id) {
        add_video_to_queue(&packet);
    } else if (packet.stream_index == player.a_id) { 
        add_sound_to_queue(&packet);
    } else {
        av_free_packet(&packet);
    }
}
```

Then in add_sound_to_queue:

```
int add_sound_to_queue(AVPacket * packet) {
AVFrame *decoded_frame = NULL;
int done = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE;
int got_frame = 0;

if (!decoded_frame) {
    if (!(decoded_frame = avcodec_alloc_frame())) {
        printf("[ADD_SOUND_TO_QUEUE] Out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
} else {
    avcodec_get_frame_defaults(decoded_frame);
}

if (avcodec_decode_audio4(player.av_acodecctx, decoded_frame, &got_frame, packet) < 0)  {
    printf("[ADD_SOUND_TO_QUEUE] Error in decoding audio\n");
    av_free_packet(packet);
    //continue;
    return -1;
}
if (got_frame) {
    int data_size;
    if (packet->size > done) {
        data_size = done;
    } else {
        data_size = packet->size;
    }
    BYTE * snd = (BYTE *)malloc( data_size * sizeof(BYTE));

    XMemCpy(snd,
        AudioBytes, 
        data_size * sizeof(BYTE)
    );

    XMemSet(&g_SoundBuffer,0,sizeof(XAUDIO2_BUFFER));

    g_SoundBuffer.AudioBytes = data_size;
    g_SoundBuffer.pAudioData = snd;
    g_SoundBuffer.pContext = (VOID*)snd;

    XAUDIO2_VOICE_STATE state;
    while( g_pSourceVoice->GetState( &state ), state.BuffersQueued > 60 ) {
        WaitForSingleObject( XAudio2_Notifier.hBufferEndEvent, INFINITE );
    }

    g_pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer( &g_SoundBuffer );
}
return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem, I have added error messages in init, opening video, codec handling etc. As mentioned before the xaudio2 code is working with an older ffmpeg, so maybe I have missed something with the avcodec_decode_audio4?

If this snappet of code isn't enough, I can post the whole code, these are just the places in the code I think the problem would be :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you accessing `decoded_frame` anywhere after decoding. How do you expect to get the data out otherwise?

```
BYTE * snd = (BYTE *)malloc( data_size * sizeof(BYTE));
```

This also looks very fishy, given that `data_size` is derived from the packet size. The packet size is the size of the compressed data, it has very little to do with the size of the decoded PCM frame.

The decoded data is located in `decoded_frame->extended_data`, which is an array of pointers to data planes, see [here](https://libav.org/doxygen/master/samplefmt_8h.html#af9a51ca15301871723577c730b5865c5) for details. The size of the decoded data is determined by `decoded_frame->nb_samples`. Note that with recent Libav versions, many decoders return planar audio, so different channels live in different data buffers. For many use cases you need to convert that to interleaved format, where there's just one buffer with all the channels. Use [libavresample](https://libav.org/doxygen/master/group__lavr.html#_details) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I saw that I didn't access decoded_frame last night, and I have changed the code a bit. I think it access the audio now because the video is in sync (play speed is the same as on any other media player). Line 34 In http://pastebin.com/Bv1fBA5M , AudioBytes was the src buffer in xmemcpy, but decoded_frame->data[0] should be now. AudioBytes is (BYTE *) while data[0] is uint8_t*. I have tried to (const void *) decoded_frame->data[0] etc. but get a ptr error xmemset. Have tried using memcpy and memset, no luck for me.